# An inequality with a constraint

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x_1,...,x_n , y_1,...,y_m$ be real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\sum_{j=1}^my_j=0$ . Then how to show that for any real numbers $a_1,...,a_n $ and $b_1,...,b_m$ ,

$2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m x_iy_j |a_i-b_j| \ge  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j |a_i-a_j|+\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m y_iy_j |b_i-b_j|$ ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? Would be curious to see a solution